# Role claim message as embed

Tags: discord.js

The below code works without any issue but I'd like to make it an embeded message with the reactions below it. I have tried many ways and even got the message to post as an embed, but couldn't get the reactions to add to it. Can someone please help me out with this.

```
const firstMessage = require('./first-message')

module.exports = bot => {
    const channelId = '781607965013966869'

    const getEmoji = emojiName => bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === emojiName)
    
    const emojis = {
        emoji: 'role',
        emoji2: 'role2',
        emoji3: 'role3',
        emoji4: 'role4'
    }
    const reactions = []

    let emojiText = "blah blah blah blah"

    for (const key in emojis) {
        const emoji = getEmoji(key)
        reactions.push(emoji)

        const role = emojis[key]
        emojiText += `${emoji} = ${role}\n`
    }

    firstMessage(bot, channelId, emojiText, reactions)

    const handleReaction = (reaction, user, add) => {
        if (user.id === `785046361077841922`) {
            return
        }

        const emoji = reaction._emoji.name
        const {
            guild
        } = reaction.message
        const roleName = emojis[emoji]
        if (!roleName) {
            return
        }
        const role = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === roleName)
        const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id)

        if (add) {
            member.roles.add(role)
        } else {
            member.roles.remove(role)
        }
    }

    bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelId) {
            handleReaction(reaction, user, true)
        }
    })

    bot.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelId) {
            handleReaction(reaction, user, false)
        }
    })
}
```

The code below makes up the first-message required

```
const addReactions = (message, reactions) => {
    message.react(reactions[0])
    reactions.shift()
    if (reactions.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(() => addReactions(message, reactions), 750)
    }
}

module.exports = async (bot, id, text, reactions = []) => {
    const channel = await bot.channels.fetch(id)

    channel.messages.fetch().then((messages) => {
        if (messages.size === 0) {
            channel.send(text).then((message) => {
                addReactions(message, reactions)
            })
        } else {
            for (const message of messages) {
                message[1].edit(text)
                addReactions(message[1], reactions)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Below is my failed attempt at making it an embed

```
const firstMessage = require('./first-message')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = bot => {
    const channelId = '781607965013966869'
    const getEmoji = emojiName => bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === emojiName)

    const emojis = {
        emoji: 'role',
        emoji2: 'role2',
        emoji3: 'role3',
        emoji4: 'role4'
    }

    const reactions = []

    for (const key in emojis) {
        const emoji = getEmoji(key)
        reactions.push(emoji)

        const role = emojis[key]
    }

    let emojiText = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ff8800')
        .setTitle('Title')
        .setDescription(`Blah blah blah blah`)
        .addField('Consoles', `${emoji} = ${role}\n`, true)
        .setFooter('Discord Server Name', 'https://fakeurl/image.png')

    firstMessage(bot, channelId, emojiText, reactions)

    const handleReaction = (reaction, user, add) => {
        if (user.id === `785046361077841922`) {
            return
        }
        const emoji = reaction._emoji.name
        const {
            guild
        } = reaction.message
        const roleName = emojis[emoji]
        if (!roleName) {
            return
        }
        const role = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === roleName)
        const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id)
        if (add) {
            member.roles.add(role)
        } else {
            member.roles.remove(role)
```

Comment: Did reaction add successful to your message . And you can capture that event . Or it don't added to your messsage.

Comment: When I created the Embed the bot would send the Embed, but not add the reactions and crash the bot, let me see if I can find that code and update the original post.

Comment: Added code to original post

Comment: What is `firstMessage` look like

Comment: That’s the middle box of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Just had to put the emojiText in the embed and then pass the embed to first-message rather than emojiText

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const firstMessage = require('./first-message')

module.exports = bot => {
    const channelId = '786073099685593088'

    const getEmoji = emojiName => bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === emojiName)

    const emojis = {
        emoji: 'role',
        emoji2: 'role2',
        emoji3: 'role3',
        emoji4: 'role4',
    }

    const reactions = []

    let emojiText = '\u200B'
    for (const key in emojis) {
    const emoji = getEmoji(key)
    reactions.push(emoji)

    const role = emojis[key]
    emojiText += `${emoji} = ${role}\n`
}

    const roleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ff6600')
        .setTitle('Blah Blah')
        .setThumbnail('https://fakeurl/image.png')
        .setDescription(`blah blah blah blah \n\n${emojiText})
        .setFooter('Discord Server Name', 'https://fakeurl/image.png')

    firstMessage(bot, channelId, roleEmbed, reactions)

    const handleReaction = (reaction, user, add) => {
        if (user.id === `785046361077841922`) {
            return
        }

        const emoji = reaction._emoji.name
        const {
            guild
        } = reaction.message
        const roleName = emojis[emoji]
        if (!roleName) {
            return
        }
        const role = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === roleName)
        const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id)

        if (add) {
            member.roles.add(role)
        } else {
            member.roles.remove(role)
        }
    }

    bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelId) {
            handleReaction(reaction, user, true)
        }
    })

    bot.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelId) {
            handleReaction(reaction, user, false)
        }
    })
}
```